# WPF - MenuIten as Icon without TEXT

Tags: wpf, menu, icons

We have been given a design (UI) for a WPF project. It contains a Menu which is represented by an Icon (No Text)

Is it possible to have a Menu button as an Icon withot text? And if so how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide the actual path to the source attribute of the image element.

```
<MenuItem>
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source=""/>
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, some examples:

having only a button without no text in it:

```
<Button Background="your color"></Button>
```

having a button with an image(icon) in it:

```
<Button>
    <image Source="your image path" Width="100" Height="100"/>
</Button>
```

this is what i can answer, you can provide more informations about what you want to do exactly so i can help :)